# error : no match for 'operator[]'

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I am solving a problem in which I m trying to pass address a 2-D array of a structure and trying to manipulate it but, whenever I use `[]` operator to access the array elements , I get a compile time error:

> no match for 'operator[]'

in my codeblocks IDE.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef struct mat
{
   int data;
   int flag;
} cell;

int mat(cell *);

int main()
{
    int m,n;
    cin>>m>>n;
    cell game[n][m];
    cout<<"The length of matrix is "<<mat(&game[0][0]);
}

int mat(cell *arr)
{
    return (sizeof(arr[0])/sizeof(arr[0][0]));
}
```

Comment: note that `sizeof(arr[0])` will not work as you think it will

Comment: note that variable-length arrays are a non-standard feature

Comment: First of all, you can't do this with C style arrays declared as you are declaring them, because they can't be dynamically sized. To do what you want with C arrays you'd have to use `malloc` to allocate heap memory.  Since you're using C++, you might find it easier to use `std::vector`

Comment: `arr[0]` is a `cell`, so `arr[0][0]` doesn't make sense. Arrays are not pointers, and pointers are not arrays.

Comment: but when use the code which I am using in the mat() function  inside main() it runs fine.

Comment: @RaviRikhi It runs fine in that case because `main`'s variable `game` *is* an array, and you're writing `game[0]` and `game[0][0]`, not `(&game[0][0])[0]` and `(&game[0][0])[0][0]`. The value you pass to `mat` is a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

```
cell game[n][m];
```

This is not legal C++. You are using a compiler-specific extension. At this point I advise you against using any compiler-specific extensions. Use standard C++ only. In standard C++ there are no Variable Length Arrays. Don't use arrays in your C++ programs. To get proper variable length array functionality. You should use `std::vector` instead, like this:

```
std::vector<std::vector<cell>> game;
```

Further,

```
&game[0][0]
```

is not an address of a 2D array. This is an address of the first element in the array. It contains no information about the number of elements. It is lost forever. You cannot pass it to some function and expect the size of the array to be recovered. To get proper array functionality with a built-in size function, use `std::vector`.

Last but not least,

```
(sizeof(arr[0])/sizeof(arr[0][0]));
```

`arr` is a `cell*`. `arr[0]` is a `cell`. `arr[0][0]` is invalid because a `cell` is neither an array not a pointer, nor it has a custom `[]` operator defined. In any case you cannot use `sizeof` to recover the number of elements in the array from a pointer to its first element. To get proper array functionality with a built-in size function, use `std::vector`.

Answer (score 1):

**Two things:**

1. Your function takes a pointer to `cell` but since you're treating it like a 2D array, you should probably change your signature to either accept a `cell ** arr` or a `cell arr[m][]` where `m` is the (fixed) size of the array and must be specified. Note that these data structures have fundamentally different representations in memory - they just have the same `[][]` syntax for accessing elements.
2. You can't use the `sizeof` function to determine the length of an array if you pass it as a pointer to an elem.  You will need to pass the dimensions along with your array, like this:

`int mat(cell **arr, int m, int n);`

Comment: This of course will not work because `cell[x][y]` is not compatible with `cell**`.

Comment: *"You can't use the sizeof function to determine the length of an array if you pass it as a pointer "* you can't query VLAs with `sizeof` at all

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Good point, though I wasn't implying you could. Just trying to explain why sizeof won't work for pointers.

Answer (score 0):

The definition being given basically says that your class doesn't define the operator [], meaning you can't use the syntax you are trying to use.